# Temp table drop in Sybase

Tags: sql, jsp, sybase, temp-tables

I have a jsp page which calls an SQL. This SQL creates a temp table and drops it at the end.

I see that the first time this code works properly but the second time it gives an error stating the temp table already exists.
This means the temp table is not getting dropped. Could you tell me what could be the reasons for it.

Comment: Show you drop and create table statements?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the same table structure try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tablename') IS NOT NULL
  TRUNCATE TABLE ##tablename
ELSE
  CREATE TABLE ##tablename(fields datatypes)
```

Comment: Im giving if object_id('#temptable')>0 drop table #temptable

Comment: i think u are missing the tempdb.. in the statement try is if object_id('tempdb..#tablename') is not null

Comment: I checked it but i get the same issue. com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybSQLException. There is already an object named #a in the database. Could there be any other possibilities?

Comment: Also geting these errors.  org.jboss.unit.NestedSQLException. tcCaught IO exception: UnknownHostException e

Answer (score -1):

Why are you creating a table if you drop it at the end of the run?
Maybe you need a [view](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) that can be permanent instead of a temporary table.
Otherwise your [drop](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_drop.asp) query is wrong I think. Probably the table name is typed.